# How to compute the dom and http load from a har file

Tags: dom, har, httpwatch

I wondering how to compute DOM and HTTP load from a HAR file.

I'm a bit confuse with my HAR file results.
The values found in the pagetiming is different from what is shown if I open the file in HTTPWatch Studio

Pagetimings:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP Load time in HttpWatch is the total elapsed time from when the page started loading until the completion of the last HTTP/HTTPS request. It's not a standard timing value in the HAR file specification and is calculated by looking at each request for a given page.

The -1 values (e.g. for onLoad in your HAR file) indicate that that there was no timing value for that event.

The onContentLoad event in the HAR file is the same as the DOM Load event shown in HttpWatch.

More information about the page event timings in HttpWatch is available here:

https://help.httpwatch.com/time_chart.html